# chef execute bash command and enter input

Tags: bash, chef-infra, knife

I want to execute this command via chef :

```
knife client delete client_name
```

The command indeed runs from chef using this :

```
bash 'delete client from chef server' do
    cwd ::File.dirname('/apps/chef-repo') # not sure if relevant
    code <<-EOH
        knife client delete client_name
    EOH
  end
```

But knife requires  confirmation input

```
STDOUT: Do you really want to client_name? (Y/N)
```

**How do I execute clicking 'Y'?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for -y (say yes to confirmation prompts). i.e.

```
 knife client delete client_name -y
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the Knife [common options](https://docs.chef.io/knife_common_options.html):

> -y, --yes
>
> Respond to all confirmation prompts with “Yes”. knife is not to ask for
>   confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct in a direct sense, but there is no reason to shell out to knife like this. You can use Chef's HTTP client directly:

```
node.chef_server_rest.delete_rest('/clients/client_name')
```

(I think, been a while)

Comment: This assumes you're already authenticated with the server. For that case the [Chef Server API](https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html#knife-api-requests) actually has an example covering the deletion of a node.